# Where to find com.sonyericsson.android.camera?

Tags: camera, sony-xperia, system-apps

i want to update Sony Camera app on my device, i tried to install the new version as normal APK but that didn't work, because of signature problems i think, i get 'package not installed', however, i think replacing the apk using root explorer (or any other similar app) would work, i tried that before with other apps and it worked well. Now the problem is that i can't locate where the apk (com.sonyericsson.android.camera) is on my device, i mean the already installed one, which i want to manually replace with newer apk.
I tried looking in /system/apps/ , it's not there.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it here (Root is not usually required to read this directory, but you should use a root-capable file explorer):

`/system/priv-app/SemcCameraUI/SemcCameraUI.apk`